# VB.NET Optional parameters - bound in caller or callee?

Tags: vb.net

If I setup optional parameters on a method in a VB.NET class, are the optional parameters supplied by the caller or the called method?

In C++, it is supplied by the called method.
In C#, it is supplied by the caller method.

Wondering how it worked in VB.NET.

Comment: However, default values are supplied by the callee. I am making this note, because optional parameters and default values tend to be used together in C# 4.0 and later.

Answer (score 3):

Caller.

> Another caveat C# folks might not know about is that the **C# version of
>   optional parameters suffers from the same limitations of the VB
>   version** (which, by the way, has been in VB since VS 2002).  Namely,
>   the optional parameter value is a compiler trick, where the optional
>   parameter value is not compiled into the method called, but instead
>   into the caller.

Read more here:  [Caveats Of C# 4-0 optional parameters](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/18/caveats-of-c-4-0-optional-parameters/)

Answer (score 2):

By the caller.  There is no universal value for "this argument was not specified" without drastically changing the method signature so the callee can't reliably tell that the argument was not supplied.  It is the compiler that digs out the default value from the assembly metadata and uses it at the call site.